# How to train multi input in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train all the data that i have with the concatenate model that have 3 input

this is the code

Augmentation

```
face_train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)

eyes_train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)

mouth_train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)

face_test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)

eyes_test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)

mouth_test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=(0.5, 0.6),
)
```

Generator

```
face_train_generator = face_train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train/face_train/',
    target_size=(38, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

eyes_train_generator = eyes_train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train/eyes_train/',
    target_size=(30, 62),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

mouth_train_generator = mouth_train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train/mouth_train/',
    target_size=(30, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

face_valid_generator = face_test_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/test/face_test/',
    target_size=(38, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

eyes_valid_generator = eyes_test_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/test/eyes_test/',
    target_size=(30, 62),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

mouth_valid_generator = mouth_test_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/test/mouth_test/',
    target_size=(30, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)
```

Model for every channel (face, eyes, mouth)

face

```
#mean

face_emotion_model = Sequential()

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(38, 38, 1), name="conv_1"))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool_1"))

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(18, 18, 6), name="conv_2"))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool_2"))

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(8, 8, 1), name="conv_3"))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool_3"))

face_emotion_model.add(Flatten(name="face_flatten"))

face_emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
face_emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

face_emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

face_emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

face_emotion_model.summary()
```

eyes

```
# variance

eyes_emotion_model = Sequential()

eyes_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 62, 1)))
eyes_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

eyes_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(14, 30, 6)))
eyes_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

eyes_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 14, 16)))
eyes_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

eyes_emotion_model.add(Flatten(name="eyes_flatten"))

eyes_emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
eyes_emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

eyes_emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

eyes_emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

eyes_emotion_model.summary()
```

mouth

```
# variance

mouth_emotion_model = Sequential()

mouth_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 38, 1)))
mouth_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

mouth_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(14, 18, 6)))
mouth_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

mouth_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 8, 16)))
mouth_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

mouth_emotion_model.add(Flatten(name="mouth_flatten"))

mouth_emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
mouth_emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

mouth_emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

mouth_emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

mouth_emotion_model.summary()
```

Get the feature from flatten layer

```
flatten_face = face_emotion_model.get_layer('face_flatten').output
flatten_eyes = eyes_emotion_model.get_layer('eyes_flatten').output
flatten_mouth = mouth_emotion_model.get_layer('mouth_flatten').output
```

Concatenate the feature and reshape

```
concatenated_features = Concatenate(axis=-1)([flatten_face, flatten_eyes, flatten_mouth])
reshaped_features = Reshape((864, 1))(concatenated_features)
output_layer = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(reshaped_features)
```

Make the model from concatenate feature

```
feature_fusion_model = Model(inputs=[face_emotion_model.input, eyes_emotion_model.input, mouth_emotion_model.input], outputs=output_layer)

feature_fusion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

this is the model summary

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 conv_1_input (InputLayer)   [(None, 38, 38, 1)]          0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6_input (InputLayer  [(None, 30, 62, 1)]          0         []                            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_9_input (InputLayer  [(None, 30, 38, 1)]          0         []                            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 36, 36, 6)            60        ['conv_1_input[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 60, 6)            60        ['conv2d_6_input[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 36, 6)            60        ['conv2d_9_input[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 18, 18, 6)            0         ['conv_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPoolin  (None, 14, 30, 6)            0         ['conv2d_6[0][0]']            
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPoolin  (None, 14, 18, 6)            0         ['conv2d_9[0][0]']            
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 conv_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 16)           880       ['pool_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 12, 28, 16)           880       ['max_pooling2d_6[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 12, 16, 16)           880       ['max_pooling2d_9[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 pool_2 (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 8, 8, 16)             0         ['conv_2[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPoolin  (None, 6, 14, 16)            0         ['conv2d_7[0][0]']            
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooli  (None, 6, 8, 16)             0         ['conv2d_10[0][0]']           
 ng2D)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 conv_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 6, 6, 32)             4640      ['pool_2[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 12, 32)            4640      ['max_pooling2d_7[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 6, 32)             4640      ['max_pooling2d_10[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 pool_3 (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 3, 3, 32)             0         ['conv_3[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPoolin  (None, 2, 6, 32)             0         ['conv2d_8[0][0]']            
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooli  (None, 2, 3, 32)             0         ['conv2d_11[0][0]']           
 ng2D)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 face_flatten (Flatten)      (None, 288)                  0         ['pool_3[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 eyes_flatten (Flatten)      (None, 384)                  0         ['max_pooling2d_8[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 mouth_flatten (Flatten)     (None, 192)                  0         ['max_pooling2d_11[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_1 (Concatenate  (None, 864)                  0         ['face_flatten[0][0]',        
 )                                                                   'eyes_flatten[0][0]',        
                                                                     'mouth_flatten[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 reshape_1 (Reshape)         (None, 864, 1)               0         ['concatenate_1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 864, 7)               14        ['reshape_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16754 (65.45 KB)
Trainable params: 16754 (65.45 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The question is how to train the 3 input from the `feature_fusion_model` ?

```
train =  feature_fusion_model.fit(
    x=[face_train_generator, eyes_train_generator, mouth_train_generator],
    steps_per_epoch= 776 // 64,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=[(face_valid_generator, eyes_valid_generator, mouth_valid_generator)],
    validation_steps= 181 // 64  
)
```

it gives me the error

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: 
(<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 
'keras.src.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: The error you're facing indicates that the data provided to the fit() method is not in a compatible format. You need to make sure that the inputs provided to the fit() method match the expected format of the model.So  In your case, you're trying to feed generators as inputs to the model, but the model is not configured to accept this type of input directly.
Given that your model incorporates multiple inputs, such as face, eyes, and mouth data, it's imperative to utilize the functional API to construct a model capable of accepting these diverse inputs. Subsequently.